# barcode scanner can not connect to the application to call the data from the database

Tags: database, apache-flex, flash, barcode-scanner, time-and-attendance

I am currently working on software for student attendance. I use the flex / flash and php to create the software but I faced a problem barcode scanner, can not connect to the application to call the data from the database when students scan the barcode printed on their student card.

Can you help me to make the script so that it can run on flex / flash and php. it makes me crazy for a week to seek a way out …. please help me: (

thanks,

Comment: the scanner can't be configured to inject the data into the keyboard buffer?

Comment: One important question: Is this a keyboard wedge scanner or an older serial port or proprietary port scanner? The later will not work without quite a bit more heavy lifting.

Comment: Or is it a scanner with a webpage running, so you can use PHP to insert the data into the database!?

Comment: @hering What is a "scanner with a webpage running"?

Comment: Maybe I'm completely wrong with my thoughts of what barcode scanner you talk about.I know this one: http://www.motorola.com/business/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=d4397b103d175110VgnVCM1000008406b00aRCRD

Comment: @hering : I use a Motorola-type barcode scanner Symbol LS2208 Laser Barcode Scanner - USB (http://www.hotpos.co.nz/pos/motorola-symbol-ls2208-laser-barcode-scanner-usb.html)

Comment: @Yann Ramin----->One important question: Is this a keyboard wedge scanner or an older serial port or proprietary port scanner? The later will not work without quite a bit more heavy lifting / tell me about it ?

Answer (score 0):

All barcode scanners I've used work like any other input device. Make sure a text input in your Flex app has focus.  Then scan, and the input should show up in the text field.

When I last built something like this; the last key from the scan was an enter key.  I don't remember if we added that explicitly when generating the bar codes or it was automatically part of it.  But, we keyed off that carriage return to perform processing.

Comment: flextras---->All barcode scanners I've used work like any other input device. Make sure a text input in your Flex app has focus. Then scan, and the input should show up in the text field. / The input has appeared on the textbox but can not call the data from the database...Do you have a script that could help this problem? I use a barcode scanning with the type of Motorola-Symbol LS2208 Laser Barcode Scanner - USB

Comment: You'll need to trigger the database call yourself.  The process of scanning into the text field should trigger keyboard events on the TextInput.  So listen to those and fire off the database call accordingly.  Without hardware, a specific samplpe, I can't give the solution. ( I do solve these sorts of problems for a living if you wanted to hire me )

Comment: flextras---->I do solve these sorts of problems for a living if you wanted to hire me / I'm asking for help if you can solve this problem ...our fellow programmers have to helping each other, in case you later have problems of course I could help too. ps : i'm using Motorola-type barcode scanner Symbol LS2208 Laser Barcode Scanner - USB and flex/flash cs5

Comment: @Richard If you want to send me a bar code scanner and your source code, with a description of your problem; I'll be more than happy to spend an hour looking into it.  http://www.flextras.com/?event=ContactForm But, I don't know what else I could do to help at this juncture.